# Get event data from an HTML drop down list (the list that drops down when a drop down list is selected) using jQuery / plain jscript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to get event data from an HTML drop down list (i.e. the list that drops down, when you click on a drop down list) using jQuery / plain jscript? I am looking to capture:

1. the number of times a user hovers over `<option>` before selecting the item they require.
2. the duration of the hover before making a selection.

At present, the events i am able to capture are for the dropdownlist element itself not the list that drops down once it is clicked upon.

Answer (score 1):

```
<select id="test">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
    <option value="4">four</option>
    <option value="5">five</option>
</select>

$(function(){
    $("#test option").mouseover(function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
    })
})
```

Works for me. You should be able to extrapolate from that to add some timers and counters to the mouseover/hover event to capture the data you want.

Comment: I don't think you will get mouseover/mouseout events on options in IE or WebKit (Safari, Chrome), so this solution is not cross-browser.

Answer (score 1):

Of the mainstream browsers only Firefox supports `mouseover`/`mouseout` events on options so you should probably abandon the first part.

As to the second part, you may be able to do something with starting a timer when the `<select>`'s `focus` event fires and stopping it when the `change` event fires, though the `focus` event is not precisely what you're after. I don't think there is an event that fires when the `<select>` is expanded.

Comment: For the first part, as this is for a research project, using Firefox is fine. For the second part the focus event is adequate as i am looking to time users from when they focus on an element (be it by selecting an item or tabbing to it). Thanks for the responses!